# Not able show text from sqlite database assets in another activity when listview clicked

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, listview

**Hi iam actually new to android iam trying to get the content from sqlite database and show that content in listview .. when the listview is clicked then it has to show the description in second activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ListView lvProduct;
private ListProductAdapter adapter;
private List<Product> mProductList;
private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
private Button btnAdd;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lvProduct = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_product);
    mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    //Check exists database
    File database = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(DatabaseHelper.DBNAME);
    if(false == database.exists()) {
        mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        //Copy db
        if(copyDatabase(this)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Copy database succes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Copy data error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }
    //Get product list in db when db exists
    mProductList = mDBHelper.getListProduct();
    //Init adapter
    adapter = new ListProductAdapter(this, mProductList);
    //Set adapter for listview
    lvProduct.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvProduct.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
```

**What is to be added in other to get the description content in secondactivity**

```
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondactivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Listviewclickvalue",columnNames);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(lvProduct);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddOrEditActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("Action", "Add");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

**Second Activity**

```
public class secondactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondactivity);

    textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtitem);

    String Tempholder=getIntent().getStringExtra("Listviewclickvalue");
    textview.setText(Tempholder);
}
}
```

it would be greatfull for the replies and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

> What is to be added in other to get the description content in
>   secondactivity

The typical way would be to get the **rowid** or an alias of **rowid** from the the **Product** in **mProductList** who's element as pointed to by **position** (passed to the `onItemClick` method). This single value(aka the **id**) can then be passed to the second activity, retrieved from that activity and then used to obtain the remaining data (columns) from the database.

An alias of **rowid** would be a column defined as `?? INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` (with the optional `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword) or it could be `?? INTEGER, ...other column definitions.... PRIMARY KEY(??)`. Where ?? would be the column name.

If the **Product** object does not hold the **id** then you can either change it so that it does hold the **id** or obtain and pass whatever values do uniquely identify the respective row.

Your passing values via the intent and retrieving them appears to look good. However **`columnNames`**, if it holds columns names rather than contents would not be able to identify a specific row.

Assuming that Product does store the **id** and you have a **`getId`** method that retrieves the **id** then you could have :-

```
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        long id_to_pass =((Product)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getId(); //<<<< Get id (recommended)
        //long id_to_pass = mProductList.get(position).getId(); //<<<< Get id (alternative)

        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondactivity.class);
        //intent.putExtra("Listviewclickvalue",columnNames); //<<<< commented out
        intent.putExtra("Listviewclickvalue",id_to_pass); //<<<< Pass id
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Of course, if you just wanted to pass data directly then you could extract it from the Product in a similar fashion to how the id is extracted above. However, there are frequent questions on here related with *"but how do I get the id so I can delete/update data in the database."*

Comment: DID NOT GET THE OUTPUT...TRY THE CODE if possible from link http://www.mediafire.com/file/87340quri44c6ae/SQLiteFromAssetExample_1.7z     Thanks for the reply ... iam new to android and java...